# Определить, каким является предикат

Tags: математика, предикат

Пожалуйста, помогите решить данное задание...

Определить, является ли данный предикат:

1. Тождественно истинным.
2. Тождественно ложным.

Ответ обосновать. 
Если не выполнено ни 1, ни 2, изобразить множество его истинности.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]